# Build Template issues when editing in VS 2010 when running VS2012 side by side

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, visual-studio-2012

I have a Build Server which is running TFS 2010 Build Service.

On my local machine I installed VS2012 alongside VS 2010. The Build templates worked fine prior to installing VS2012.

After I installed VS2012 I now have issues with the Build Templates when editing them in VS2010.

I have solved the IBuildDetail errors I were getting by visiting the following blog:

[IBuildDetail Not Defined error fix](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/yuvmaz/archive/2011/12/12/ibuilddetail-not-defined-error-in-tfs-2010-build-templates.aspx)

However i am trying to fix the remaining errors e.g:

```
Compiler errors encountered Processing Expression "New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildSettings()".
"BuildSettings" is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.'
```

I more errors like the above.

Could anyone share how I could fix the above error/related errors please?

I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same problem when upgrading TFS 2010 to TFS 2012.

The exact problem:

> Your awesome custom activities were built against TFS 2010 bits. Loading your custom assemblies in the TFS 2012 build service process triggers loading TFS 2010 assemblies, and the Workflow Foundation (WF) services are not happy about that.

Here is the steps to solve the problem:
[Upgrading your build definitions from TFS2010 to TFS2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/10/24/upgrading-your-build-definitions-from-tfs2010-to-tfs2012.aspx)

And here workaround:
[Your custom assemblies need update, or else, redirecting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/duat_le/archive/2012/03/16/your-custom-assemblies-need-update-or-else-redirecting.aspx)

May be I'm wrong about your case, but these links can drive you to your own solution.